# Reference custom user control property with variable

Tags: vb.net

I have created a custom user control Called MyRectangle which has 2 public properties: bedwidth and bedlength.

i have no issue setting these directly in code, for example:

```
MyRectangle1.bedwidth = 2.95
MyRectangle2.bedwidth = 53.61
MyRectangle3.bedwidth = 29.28
```

The form contains also a Button, a TextBox and a ComboBox which is populated with the names of all the rectangles

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ComboBox1.Items.Add("MyRectangle1")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("MyRectangle2")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("MyRectangle3")

end sub
```

When the button is Clicked i would like the value of the TextBox assigned to the property of the rectangle that is chosen from the ComboBox. for example:

```
Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim RectangleName as String = ComboBox1.text

me.controls(RectangleName).bedwidth = textbox1.text

end sub
```

However i am getting the error:

```
 Error  3   'BedWidth' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.
```

I have successfully used labels and label1.text in place of the rectangles,
how can i access the custom properties in this way?
is there perhaps some code i have missed when constructing my custom user control?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried casting it?  CType(me.controls(RectangleName), NameOfCustomControlClass).bedwidth

Comment: @the_lotus, that should be `DirectCast` rather than `CType`.

Comment: @the_lotus thanks for the help lotus, i tried  DirectCast(Me.Controls(rectanglename), MyRectangle).BedWidth = TextBox1.Text  but i am now getting object ref not set to an instance,  any idea?

Comment: @sawsine : That means that the control by the specified name was not found. If it's located in a subcontrol (for example a `Panel`) you either need to access `Controls` on that instead, or use a recursive lookup such as [`Me.Controls.Find(RectangleName, True)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2). Note that the last suggestion returns an _array_ of all controls with the specified name that was found somewhere in your form (or an empty array, if there were none).

Comment: Wonderful advice Vincent,  i managed to get everything working